Android Talkback announcing version string as Date in WebView
Android Talkback announces the version information incorrectly in date format as “February 5th, 1446, when focuses on the app version string '2.5.1446'.
There is an html page which contains version number.

Does this answer your question? How can I override a screen-reader's pronunciation of a word in a sentence without having it pause mid-sentence?

No didn't found the solution.

It’s great that you are looking into how screen readers announce your app. When developers do so, it’s a common repel how screen readers read certain, sometimes domain-specific, pieces of information. The consensus in the accessibility sphere is not to change it. Screen reader users are familiar with their SR and how it (mis)pronounces stuff. That’s what the linked answer proposes: Don‘t. It provides additional details about the reasons.

I just formatted the version string to (2.5).1446 instead of 2.5.1446. I enclosed major version and minor version with simple braces. I added the aria-label with the formatted string. Android Talkback is reading fine.

The issue is that now braille display users will get braces, and so will screen reader users who ask to spell the version string out for better understanding.

The html code will look like this:
2.5.1446